# Unable to import nltk on mac os x

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, nltk, spyder

I had successfully installed nltk [from this site](http://www.nltk.org/install.html). And just to validate i am able to import it from the terminal. But when i execute my python script from the Spyder it gives me following error in Spyders terminal

```
File "/Prateek/Python/RC_ISSUES/algorithm_RC.py", line 9, in <module>
import nltk

ImportError: No module named nltk
```

Below output is from the terminal

[image: Importing nltk from the terminal]

I know there might be similar questions but i thought it is different from rest of the other questions

Comment: Have you checked that spyders is using the same python as you invoked from the command line? Maybe it has it's own, or needs to be pointed at the system python.

Comment: I am beginner in python, so how do you check whether it is pointing the system python or not?.

Comment: Add this line: `import sys; print sys.version` to your code before `import nltk` in `algorithm_RC.py`

Comment: @alvas, it shows `2.7.10 (default, Jun  1 2015, 09:45:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]`

Comment: Voila, different versions, one compiled on `Oct 23 2015` and another `Jun 1 2015` =)

Comment: The same situation could happen on windows, given you've had installed multiple version of python on the system. Here your issue is that you have two pythons, one that the script is reaching (likely to be the one installed with the system) and another that you installed manually (usually with port or brew).

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a python script, the operating system is looking for the interpreter as specified on the first line of the script, which most of the time is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

On Mac OS X, this is the python as distributed with the system when you installed it, which is the one distributed with the system. It is usually very likely to be the one that has the older compilation date:

```
2.7.10 (default, Jun 1 2015, 09:45:55) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

If you do `type python` in your shell, you're very likely to see another path to that interpreter, e.g. if you installed the brew version of python:

```
% type python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
```

So you have two ways around it, either you explicitly launch your script with python:

```
python algorithm_RC.py
```

in doubt, use the full path you found out with `type`:

```
/usr/local/bin/python algorithm_RC.py
```

or, you can change your script first line with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

which will use the same python as the one you're reaching from your shell. You can also use the full path to your manually installed python, by making that line:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

or whatever the `type` command gave. But I would advise you against that, as the `/usr/bin/env` solution is more flexible and makes sure you're using in both cases the same python from the shell and within the script.

Finally, you can also use the system's python by calling explicitly `easy_install` from `/usr/bin`:

```
sudo /usr/bin/pip nltk
```

And if you don't have pip there, then you'll have to install it first:

```
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip
```

HTH

Comment: thanks for your inputs. But i want to run in spyder. So that it will be very useful to debug the script

Answer (score 0):

try 1:

```
>>>import nltk
```

and hit enter and now try

```
>>>nltk.download()
```